# sort columns in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I have a data in individual columns in a table (Total) in SAS as below:

```
columnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD
 20      30       10       50
```

I want to sort the columns in descending order of their values. i.e. the output should be as below :

```
columnD ColumnB ColumnA ColumnC
  50      30       20       10
```

How to get the above output in SAS code?

Comment: So as to not reinvent the wheel: http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/319-2013.pdf

Comment: This question doesn't meet SO rules. Please post what you've tried so far and what didn't work, especially in the future. You'll get faster responses this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go:

```
data old;
a=20;
b=30;
c=10;
d=50;
run;

proc transpose data = old out=tran;
var _all_;
run;

proc sort data=tran out = sort;
by descending col1 ;
run;

proc transpose data = sort out=new (drop=_NAME_);
var col1;
id _NAME_;
run;
```